# ¿Cómo prevenir Error 500 Asp.Net archivo duplicado?

Tags: javascript, html, c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Dispongo de un formulario en el cual tengo que guardar un pdf desde el cliente al servidor, estoy usando MVC con la siguiente estructura:

**VISTA:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("", "FormularioPdf", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.Partial("_Formulario");
}
```

**VISTA PARCIAL:**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="label-color" for="numTarjeta">Documento PDF:</label>
    <input type="file" class="form-control" id="docupdf" name="docupdf" accept="application/pdf">
</div>
```

**JAVASCRIPT:**

```
function GuardarDocumento(documento) {
            try {
                var cont = $('#docupdf').get(0).files.length;

                if (cont == 1) {
                    var data = new FormData();
                    var files = $("#docupdf").get(0).files;

                    if (files.length > 0) {
                        console.log("files", files[0]);
                        data.append("file", files[0]);                      
                    }

                    var ajaxRequest = $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "PdfUpload",
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false,
                        data: data
                    });


                    ajaxRequest.done(function (xhr, textStatus) {
                        // Do other operation
                    });                 
                }
            } catch (e) {
                console.log("Error view",e)
            }
        }
```

**CONTROLADOR:**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult PdfUpload()
{
   try
   {
        if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            var file = Request.Files[0];

            if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
            {
                var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/pdf/"), fileName);
                file.SaveAs(path);
            }
        }
    } catch(Exception e)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Error: " + e);
    }

    return View();
}
```

Al insertar en el input un archivo ya guardado y realizando el POST salta el 500

**¿Cómo puedo prevenir ese error?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para prevenir ese error, en el controlador hay que añadir una comprobación de la ruta con `System.IO.File.Exists(path)`

En mi caso el código ha quedado de la siguiente manera:

```
if (Request.Files.Count > 0)
{
    var file = Request.Files[0];

    if (file != null && file.ContentLength > 0)
    {
        var fileName = Path.GetFileName(file.FileName);
        path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/pdf/"), fileName);

        var existe = System.IO.File.Exists(path) ? return null : file.SaveAs(path);

        if (existe == false)
        {
            file.SaveAs(path);
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }

    }
}

return Content(path);
```